# ArangoDB HTTP/AQL CREATE INDEX

Tags: indexing, arangodb, aql

To ensure unique edges in my edge collection I can index `_from` and `_to` fields as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Indexing/Hash.html#ensure-uniqueness-of-relations-in-edge-collections)

```
db.edges.ensureIndex({ type: "hash", fields: [ "_from", "_to" ], unique: true });
```

The above operation can only be performed from `arangosh`. However I am writing a setup function that is supposed to create all the required vertex and edge collection mostly through the HTTP API. I need to know how to perform the same action through `AQL` or HTTP Api.

Answer (score 0):

AQL does not provide any means for data-definition language operations, such as creating/dropping databases, collections or indexes.

The purpose of AQL is running data selection and data modification queries against an ArangoDB database.

Data-definition operations can be carried out via ArangoDB's HTTP API, the ArangoDB web interface or the Arango shell (arangosh). The latter two will use the regular HTTP API of ArangoDB too.

Comment: How Can this action be performed through HTTP Api ? Without using arangosh ?

Comment: the most easiest way is to use wireshark or ngrep to follow whats arangosh doing to achieve this. Altenatively [looking at the HTTP-Index documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/latest/HTTP/Indexes/) or exploring it via the swagger interface in the ArangoDB Webui could be usefull.

Comment: Please note that you were reading the outdated ArangoDB 3.0 documentation (according to your link)